# ffmpeg mp4 to hls chunks of similar duration

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am using below command to convert `mp4` to `hls` format using `ffmpeg`. Everything is working fine expect for the fact that the output chunk have random duration chunk size.

```
ffmpeg -i ad1.mp4 -strict -2 preset:v veryfast -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename 'sample-%06d.ts' -f hls sample.m3u8
```

I even tried using `-hls_time 10` it somewhat solves my issue, the time is not 10 static. I can totally bear the first and last chunk of different size than specified. Is there any strict way to do that.

Sample Output: [Link](https://pastebin.com/iPUeUW1H)

Output when using -hls_time 10: [Link](https://pastebin.com/57KrQtsc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HLS and similar muxers only split at keyframes, so add segment time and force keyframes to align with segment time.

```
-force_key_frames expr:'gte(t,n_forced*10)' -hls_time 10
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Just one query  does this force_key_frames have any side affect.

Comment: What kind of side-effects? Some rate-distortion will likely occur, since the encoder may not have placed a keyframe at that point otherwise.